# Numpy isclose for Arrays - TypeError: Not implemented for this type

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have 2 .csv (.tsv) sheets which i load in Arrays. Now I want to compare every cell of these two arrays by the numpy isclose function.

It works with normal numbers but not with my arrays.

```py
with open(filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        point.append(row[0])

with open(filename2) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        point2.append(row[0])

print(numpy.isclose(point,point2, atol=0.01))
```

Error:

```
print(numpy.isclose(point,point2, atol=0.01))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2306, in isclose
    xfin = isfinite(x)
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Even if I try direct entries from the Array (e.g. point[3],point2[3]) I got the mistake.

Comment: What is the content of your csv files? You can only compare numbers as far as I know using numpy.isclose. In case your csv files contain only numbers you need to convert the strings provided by the reader into numbers first. i.e. print(numpy.isclose(point.astype(np.float),point2.astype(np.float), atol=0.01))

Comment: `point` and `point2` are lists.  `isclose` has to turn them into arrays (`np.array(point)`) to compare them.  And it expects numeric array, no strings.  The error occurs when it tries to check one of the arrays for a `np.inf` values, a float operation.  Construct proper `numpy` arrays first, check the dtype, and modify if needed.   You can't begin to compare them without fully understanding what you have loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.reader` reads strings – you end up with two lists of strings.

You'll probably want to cast the values to `float` (or something else maybe if you need more precision) as you read the lines.

```py
with open(filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    point1 = [float(row[0]) for row in reader]

with open(filename2) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    point2 = [float(row[0]) for row in reader]

print(numpy.isclose(point1, point2, atol=0.01))
```